# find locks on a table with specifc row sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

the below query will give me the lock on a table

```
select distinct object_name(id)
from master..syslocks
```

what I am searching is to find out on which row its locking ?

for example if I got `update messages set name ='hi' where id =1` and messages  is causing locks, I want a query to know that id =1 for this table is causing locking. can I know that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it depends if you table is using AllPages/Datapages/Datarows lock scheme (see output of "sp_help *tablename*")

If it is Datarows, you can get a lock on specific row, otherwise locks will be on page (data or index or both) or on the table.
Using syslocks or sp_lock, you can retrieve the page involved in the lock.
To print the content of the page, you could run "dbcc page (database_id,pageno,4)"

Comment: I was trying to use `dbcc page` where should i get databse_id ? from syslocks ? column `dbid`? and pageno from column `page` in syslocks ?

Comment: Yes column dbid and page.